# HTTP Requests when using REST

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I'm trying to write a REST API. I honestly do not know anything related to REST structure so I've done some research and find a valuable information that one of the key things that separates REST from other structures is that it utilizes the 'GET','POST','PUT','DELETE' requests of HTTP.

This might come out silly but how can i control the request type. For example if I code it and simply enter a URL **www.example.com/users/1234** , how will my server side analyze whether its a GET,POST,PUT or DELETE request.

Sorry if I'm asking an obvious question, but I would love have some information related to this subject

Comment: The type of request is contained in the request. But how you read it depends on how you implement the server. i.e. which language/framework you use. So, which one is it?

Comment: @ArjunShankar First, thank you for your consideration. I'm planning to build it on basic LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is by looking at the [SO wiki associated with the <kbd>rest</kbd> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info).  This is a part of SO that is so often overlooked as a great source of information.  Just hover over the tag and select the ["info"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info) link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned LAMP, I post here, a minimal PHP script which is aware of the method being called:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { 
    echo "Got a POST Request";
  } else {
    echo "Got a non-POST Request";
  }
?>
```

Look at this document which describes a lot of 'standard' PHP variables containing information about and content from the request, and so on:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

If you install and run Apache with the PHP module enabled, and serve a PHP file like the above, requesting that file from a client will return the appropriate string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but here is the thing I wonder. When I code a REST API how does client can possibly make a POST or PUT request. I mean assume he enters the link **example.com/users/123** this means he wants to obtain information related to user id 123. But like in this URL form how can a client make a PUT request so I can handle it. Without the RESTful approach I would say example.com/users.php?id=123&methodType=PUT but I know that REST does not allow. Sorry if I've written it too complicated

Comment: That depends on the client. I wouldn't expect a RESTful service to be accessed with a plain browser where the user types the URL. That's too cumbersome You'd be writing a client using, maybe, an HTTP library. This again depends on the language/platform/framework you want to use for the client.